# When interviewing for your current job how do you describe your experience?

Tags: interviewing

My current job is classed as contract and it will be soon a copy of it will be posted externally.  There will be no differences in the description in the job I applied for as contractor and the permanent position with the exception that the new position will be full-time permanent.

During the interview I am wondering what familiarity I should use when describing my experience at the company.

For example if my current employer is called WidgetCo:

> I have "X" experience when I worked with Danny in HR.

or

> I have "X" experience when I worked at WidgetCo with a member of HR.

Also, the interview panel will consist of the people I currently work with.  When describing experiences do I say that when I worked on the "Y" project do I say his/her name or "a co-worker"?

Comment: -1 for way overthinking it. You're not going to survive tough interviews by focusing on trivia.

Comment: You survive interviews by eliminating problems before they occur.  I could not worry about this and just guess during the time of the interview or I could have an answer before I go in.  Since I don't interview often getting matters of social protocol out of the way immediately allows me to concentrate on other important things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the people who are interviewing you will know the people you are talking about, use names.  I'd use full names (not just "Danny").  I think it would be weird to interview within your current company and not name the people you worked with.  You should certainly name anyone who was pleased with your work and would give you a good reference if the interviewers asked.